Which software engineering design patterns are most commonly applicable in building pipelines and other DE/DS/ML workflows?
In software engineering, a design pattern is a general, reusable solution to a common problem in software design. It is not a finished piece of code but rather a template or best practice that can be applied to specific challenges in different contexts. Design patterns were popularised by the Gang of Four (GoF) in their 1995 book Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software. These patterns provide proven solutions for creating flexible, reusable, and maintainable code. Over time, many of these patterns have been adapted beyond traditional software development into fields like data science, where they help to manage complexity in data pipelines, model training, and system architecture.
The goal of this question is to explore how several key software engineering design patterns can be adapted to the unique needs of data science projects, making workflows more scalable, modular, and easier to maintain.
References:
Gamma, E., Helm, R., Johnson, R., & Vlissides, J. (1993). Design patterns: Abstraction and reuse of object-oriented design. In ECOOP’93—Object-Oriented Programming: 7th European Conference Kaiserslautern, Germany, July 26–30, 1993 Proceedings 7 (pp. 406-431). Springer Berlin Heidelberg
Gamma, E., Helm, R., Johnson, R., & Vlissides, J. (1995). Design patterns: Elements of reusable object-oriented software. Addison-Wesley Longman Publishing Co., Inc.

"Producer and Consumer" pattern is obvious for a pipeline of anything.

it's maybe too obvious but I would add "pipeline and filters'' as the fundamental pattern to the list?

Several software engineering design patterns can be effectively adapted to improve data science and data engineering workflows and pipelines. Typically these are implemented using principles of object-oriented design. Originally, the GoF book was based around C++. These days, while C++ (or C) is still used for most of the heavy lifting (ie., the nuts and bolts of algorithm implementation, it is far more common for the interfaces to these to be written in Python (eg., numpy, scipy and libraries such as Tensorflow, Torch, scikit, keras etc.).  Here are some widely applicable patterns in data science and engineering, presented in alphabetical order:
Adapter: Converts the interface of a class into one expected by the client. This is useful when integrating different libraries or frameworks that use varying interfaces for similar tasks. An adapter can convert data formats before feeding them into a model, ensuring smooth integration between different systems. For example, if you're moving between Pandas DataFrames and PySpark objects, an adapter could be used to handle the transformation without modifying the core logic.
Builder: This pattern constructs complex objects step-by-step. In data science, the Builder pattern is helpful for creating flexible, modular pipelines where different steps (eg., preprocessing, feature selection, model training) can be assembled dynamically based on the needs of the dataset or the task. This is especially useful in hyperparameter tuning and workflow automation where various combinations of steps need to be tested for optimisation. Tools like Kubeflow Pipelines use a builder-like approach to assemble complex ML workflows.
Chain of Responsibility: Passes a request along a chain of handlers, where each handler processes the request or passes it to the next handler. In data pipelines, different preprocessing stages (e.g., data cleaning, transformation, feature extraction) can be implemented as separate handlers, allowing each stage to process the data sequentially. This can be particularly useful when working with Apache Spark or Kafka for processing streaming data, though care must be taken to avoid introducing latency if too many stages are chained.
Decorator: This pattern allows for dynamically adding responsibilities to objects. It can extend models with additional functionality, such as logging, cross-validation, or caching, without modifying the underlying model. For example, you could "decorate" a base model with logging to track metrics during training, or with caching to store results from expensive computations.
Factory Method: This pattern provides an interface for creating objects but allows subclasses to decide which class to instantiate. In data science, it can be used for dynamic model selection, where a machine learning model is chosen based on input data characteristics or user preferences. For instance, a factory can instantiate different models like logistic regression, random forests, or neural networks without changing the pipeline. This pattern is particularly useful in automated machine learning (AutoML) frameworks where models are selected based on performance metrics.
Observer: Defines a one-to-many dependency between objects so that when one object changes, its dependents are notified automatically. This is useful in monitoring the training process. For example, observers can watch for changes in metrics like loss or accuracy and trigger actions such as early stopping or saving the best model. In modern machine learning frameworks like Keras or TensorFlow, this can be seen in the implementation of callbacks to monitor and adjust training.
Producer-Consumer:
This pattern is a fundamental building block for task-based pipelines, where producers generate tasks (or data), and consumers process them. Producers add tasks to a shared queue, and consumers pull tasks for processing. This pattern is highly applicable in batch processing, parallel workloads, and streaming data pipelines. The decoupling between producers and consumers allows for dynamic scaling of consumers based on the volume of data, making it particularly effective in distributed systems or stream processing tools like Apache Kafka, RabbitMQ, or Apache Flink.
Example: In a machine learning pipeline, producers could load and preprocess data, while consumers might perform model training or evaluation tasks in parallel.
Proxy: Provides a surrogate or placeholder for another object to control access to it. This pattern can be applied to handling large datasets or distributed systems. For example, proxies can manage access to external APIs or cloud-based machine learning models, ensuring efficient data processing and reducing resource load. It can also be useful when dealing with lazy loading large datasets, where the proxy only loads data as needed to reduce memory overhead.
Pub/Sub Bus: The Pub/Sub Bus pattern is widely used in event-driven architectures and streaming pipelines. In this pattern, producers (publishers) send events or messages to a central message bus, and multiple consumers (subscribers) listen for these events and react accordingly. This enables real-time processing and allows multiple components to consume the same data independently, increasing scalability. It's often used in streaming pipelines, where real-time data needs to be processed by multiple systems simultaneously.
Example: In a data science workflow, a pipeline that ingests real-time data from IoT devices could use a Pub/Sub system like Apache Kafka, with multiple services subscribed to perform real-time monitoring, logging, and data transformation.
Singleton: Ensures a class has only one instance and provides a global point of access. In data science, Singleton can manage shared resources like database connections, configuration settings, or logging services. Tools such as MLflow or Weights & Biases could be implemented as Singletons to ensure only one instance of an experiment tracker is created. However, caution should be taken in distributed systems, as Singleton could introduce synchronisation issues when multiple processes attempt to access the shared state simultaneously.
Strategy: Defines a family of algorithms, encapsulates each one, and makes them interchangeable. In machine learning, this pattern is ideal for switching between different models or optimisation techniques dynamically, based on performance or data characteristics. For instance, switching between gradient descent variants or tree-based models based on current results. In frameworks like SciPy or TensorFlow, the optimisation strategy (eg., SGD, Adam) can be encapsulated and swapped during training based on the specific problem.
Template Method: Defines the skeleton of an algorithm, with steps that can be overridden by subclasses. In data science, it can be used to structure a pipeline with fixed steps such as data loading, preprocessing, model training, and evaluation, while allowing specific steps to be customised depending on the task or model. This is useful in frameworks like Scikit-learn’s pipelines, which define the overall structure while allowing for different transformers or models to be used in the pipeline.
Best Practices and Considerations:
These patterns enable modularity, reusability, and maintainability in data science projects, particularly as workflows grow in complexity. However, it's important to balance flexibility with simplicity, as over-engineering can introduce unnecessary complexity. Patterns like Factory and Strategy are particularly useful in situations that require frequent model experimentation, while Singleton and Observer can optimise resource management and monitoring in large-scale, distributed environments. When applying these patterns, consider their impact on system latency, complexity, and fault tolerance.
By applying these patterns judiciously, data scientists can create more scalable, maintainable, and flexible pipelines, improving collaboration and reducing technical debt as projects evolve.
